# How to correct math formula display in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ckeditor

I'm using math formula in ckeditor, when I input text into textbox, it will put down text below and display correct math formula in ckeditor.

For example: 
I input text

```
\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)
```

It will put down text and dispslay correct format of math in ckeditor..

this is my source:

```
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['\\(','\\)']]}});</script>     
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.1/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.3/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>

<script>
function displayResult() {
    var first = CKEDITOR.instances.first.getData();

    var maincontent = "";
    maincontent = "<p>" + first + "</p>";
    // CKEDITOR.instances.
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = maincontent;

}
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="text" id="first" value="\(x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}\)">
  <button onclick="displayResult();">Click me!!!</button>
  <span><div id="content"></div></span>

 </body>
</html>
```

however I get an error happen:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getData' of undefined
>       at displayResult (testMath.html:10)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (testMath.html:23)

How to fix this error and display correct format of ckeditor? Thanks so much !

Comment: You haven't defined any CKEditor instances, hence `CKEditor.instances.first` is null.

Comment: Hi @RoryMcCrossan: you can give more detail.. sorry Im a newbie

Comment: In other words, ` var first = CKEDITOR.instances.first` doesn't reference anything. This line of code effectively means nothing, it's empty, disconnected

Comment: I know that, but I need more detail for this case